Rendering issues with our .Net application post windows patch
Recently, we've encountered rendering issues with our .NET application following a Windows patch update for Windows 10 Version 22H2. Specifically, after applying the cumulative update for .NET Framework 3.5, 4.8, and 4.8.1, we've noticed intermittent problems with image rendering in our application.
One of our clients, who utilizes our application built on C# based .NET Framework 4.8 which utilizes ActiveX to draw the images(JPG) to the front end, reported sporadic occurrences of missing images. These images are stored on the web server where our application is hosted.
Could anyone else who has applied the same Windows update and .NET Framework cumulative update share their experiences? Have you encountered any performance issues or rendering glitches post-update? Additionally, has anyone faced similar challenges with missing images in web-hosted applications?
Any insights, tips, or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
We tried to reproduce the issue however it barely happens so it makes so difficult to figure out the problem
